# Last date when the user ran the app in android?

Tags: android, time

How can I know the last time when the user ran the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the current date in the `onResume`

Comment: in onResume of first activity?

Comment: or not. depends on what date you are looking for.

Comment: when application starts, I get some data from a server. I want to know which is the last data when application ran for knowing if I have to get data from server or not

Comment: Whenever you retrieve the data, save the date. Then you know when your last retrieval was.

Comment: can I save it in shared preferences?

Comment: Save it to sharedPreferences in onResume or in the method that you use to handle the update data.